# Loading ActiveRecord fixtures with RSpec without Rails

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec, rails-activerecord

I am using some `ActiveRecord` models outside of `Rails` for which I am writing unit tests. In my tests, I would like to be able to use fixtures and thought I would use some of [rspec-rails](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails) features for that. I cannot simply use `require "rspec-rails"` because it has some Rails dependencies and I am not using Rails.

Here is the `spec_helper` I am using:

```
require 'active_record'
require 'active_record/fixtures'
require 'active_support'
require 'rspec/rails/extensions/active_record/base'
require 'rspec/rails/adapters'
require 'rspec/rails/fixture_support'  # Includes ActiveRecord::TestFixtures
                                       # into the RSpec config

require 'my_models'

# Setup database connection
environment = "test"
configuration = YAML::load(File.open('config/database.yml'))
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(configuration[environment])

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fixture_path = File.expand_path("../../test/fixtures", __FILE__)

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = "random"

  # Run each test inside a DB transaction
  config.around(:each) do |test|
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      test.run
      raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
    end
  end
end
```

And here is an example of a test

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Transaction do

  before :each do
    self.class.fixtures :users, :merchants
  end

  it "should do this and that" do
    ...
  end
end
```

The problem is that, this way, the fixtures are not loaded. I looked into the `rspec-rails` code but cannot figure out what module I should extend or method I should call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After diving into the Active Record code, I figured that the reason why the fixtures were not loaded was because I had not set `ActiveRecord::Base.configurations`. The following fixed the issue:

```
configuration = YAML::load(File.open('config/database.yml'))
ActiveRecord::Base.configurations = configuration
```